# How to take inputs from array and input it into an equation in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, input

My goal is to try and create a program that takes in grades in percents and multiply it with their weight value (either in decimal form or percent form). The equation is basically:

Overall grade = (grade1*weightInDecimal1)+(grade2*weightInDecimal2)+(grade3*weightInDecimal3)+...

or

Overall grade = (grade1*weight%1)+(grade2*weight%2)+(grade3*weight%3)+...

---

Is there a way to store the inputs and then recall it later in the code? Or possibly a more efficient way?

I also want to try and make a dynamic array. I want to make a program that asks the user for how many assignments they have and makes an array based on that. That way it's not stuck at 4 assignments

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numbers[4][2];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
       cout<<"Grade #"<<i<<endl;
       cin>>numbers[i][0];
       cout<<"Weight for grade #"<<i<<":"<<endl;
       cin>>numbers[i][1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "|" << numbers[i][0]*numbers[i][1]<< "|";
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector` instead of an array? Then you could dynamically add as many elements as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what structs are for

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

struct entry {
    int grade;
    int weight;
    int gradeWeight; //grade*weight 
};

int main() {
    array<entry,4> numbers;
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.max_size();i++)
    {
       cout<<"Grade #"<<i<<endl;
       cin>>numbers[i].grade;
       cout<<"Weight for grade #"<<i<<":"<<endl;
       cin>>numbers[i].weight;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.max_size(); i++)
    {
        numbers[i].gradeWeight = numbers[i].grade*numbers[i].weight;
        cout << "|" << numbers[i].gradeWeight << "|";
    }
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can also increase the amount of numbers by just increasing the array size.

Comment: You should `#include <array>`

Comment: Thank you very much. One should test code before posting it ^^

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to avoid using arrays (dynamic or otherwise).  See for example Stroustrup's FAQ entry [What's wrong with arrays?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#arrays)  As Greg suggests in the comments you will most likely write better quality code if you use a container like [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

If you can calculate or input the size of your container before allocating it you can (if you wish) pass that size to the constructor ...

```
auto syze{ 0 };
auto initialValue{ 0 };

// calculate or input syze
. . .

// dynamically allocate an "array"
// of ints and an "array" of floats
std::vector<int> grades(syze, initialValue);
std::vector<float> weights(syze, initialValue);
```

On the other hand if you prefer to use a container that dynamically grows to hold data as it arrives you can do that too...

```
// dynamically allocate an empty "array"
// of ints and an empty "array" of floats
std::vector<int> grades;
std::vector<float> weights;

while (...condition...)
{
    std::cin >> g;   // input a grade ...
    std::cin >> w;   // ... and a weight

    // grow the containers by adding 
    // one item at the end of each
    grades.emplace_back(g);
    weights.emplace_back(w);
}
```

**Update**

I should have pointed out how to calculate the result from the two vectors.  You can calculate your overall grade with just one more line of code by using `std::inner_product` from the STL's `<numeric>` header.  Note that in the code below the last argument is 0.0 (rather than just 0) so that `std::inner_product` returns a `double` rather than an `int`.  That avoids any risk of `float` values being truncated to `int` (and avoids some pretty ugly warnings from the compiler).

```
auto overallGrade = std::inner_product(grades.begin(), grades.end(), weights.begin(), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by others, if you ask the user for how many assignments they have, `std::array` is a wrong container because it's dimension is fixed at compile time.

As others, I discurage the use of direct memory allocation but the use of `std::vector` to manage it.

I just suggest the use of `reserve()` (method of `std::vector`), when you know how many assignments.

The following is a full example using, instead a couple of `std::vector` of `int`, a single `std::vector` of `std::pair<int, int>`

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   int                              valG, valW;
   std::size_t                      dim;
   std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec; 

   std::cout << "How many grade/weight couples? ";
   std::cin  >> dim;

   vec.reserve(dim);

   for ( auto i = 0U ; i < dim ; ++i )
    {
      std::cout << "Grade #" << i << "? " << std::endl;
      std::cin  >> valG;
      std::cout << "Weight for grade #" << i << "? " << std::endl;
      std::cin  >> valW;

      vec.emplace_back(valG, valW);
    }

    for ( auto const & p : vec )
       std::cout << '|' << (p.first * p.second) << '|';

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```